# Shiny Download an excel file

Tags: r, excel, shiny

I have a `shiny` server set up on a Linux instance
I have a folder called templates which has a excel file template
The user goes to the web page and presses a download button and in theory they should be able to download the template wherever they like on their local machine.

I have seen the code from the post [Shiny download file not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35081961/shiny-download-file-not-working)

When i try and run it i get a file saved to `my downloads` on my windows laptop and it is called NA not the name Template.xlsx

My two questions are

- Is it possible to prompt the user where to save the file locally
- Is it possible to make it default to an `XLSX`

The pseudo code is

```
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

 # Side Panel with Options
  fluidRow(
    column(4, wellPanel(
  id = "leftPanel",
  div(
    id = "Header",
    h3("Options"),
    tags$hr()
  ),
  div(
    h4("1.  Download the empty excel template"), 
    downloadButton("downloadBtn", "Download Excel Template")
      )
)))))
```

## Server

```
# Define server logic required
server <- shinyServer(
  function(input, output) {

output$downloadBtn <- downloadHandler(
  filename = function() {
    paste(input$filenames, sep='')
  },
  content = function(file) {
    myfile <- srcpath <- '/home/foo/Save to Database/templates/Template.xlsm'
    file.copy(myfile, file)
  }
  )})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `paste(input$filenames, sep='')` but you don't have input$filenames defined in the UI part. It should work if you replace that line with `"Template.xlsm"`